# Force execution only of .php scripts?

Tags: php, execution, malware-detection

Is there a way to configure your server in a way that it will execute only scripts with the .php extension? This makes things easier when looking for malicious code in your folders. Possible? Is this the default? Would this work also with includes?

Comment: That's the default in every stock PHP install I've ever come across. Try putting PHP code in a `.js` or `.html` file and see.

Comment: Ok, so why some people is pretending that malware can be hidden in binary files such as images?

Comment: Because there's a lot of badly written validation code out there. Examples: https://phocean.net/2013/09/29/file-upload-vulnerabilities-appending-php-code-to-an-image.html https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/111935/exploiting-a-php-server-with-a-jpg-file-upload etc.

Comment: Your best way of avoiding *that* is to send all untrusted user uploads to static hosting like Amazon S3 (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html) instead of to your PHP server. Safest method.